# iOS 10.3.2: cookies will return after deletion. How to clean-up?

Tags: ios, cookies

I discoverd that in iOS 10.3.2 (german language set, timezone Berlin / MESZ) in my iPad not every information concerning history and tracking could be deleted:

Following Einstellungen (Setting), Safari, Erweitert (more or extended), Website-Daten (website data) there is a list of pages visited (I assume with cookies set). When I'm trying "delete all" none of the entries will disappear. I tried additionally deleting one by one. By entering this part of setting again (even without using safari in the meanwhile) there are some of the entries there again, some of them with 0 bytes. Resetting / rebooting iPad or cleaning history completely before deleting or combination of different steps cookies still are there.

Are the domains which are listed in some sense untrustworthy? Or do they use some "irregular" code / approach? The most persistant ones are

- onedigitals.co.uk
- parismatch.com
- dove.com

Additional some google-domains (domains containing string google) and spiegel.de could be very often seen. Or some new sort of supercookies (but they are flash aren't they - and iOS does not support flash)? Or bug in iOS?

[Perhaps related to](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280881/unwanted-safari-cookies-that-cant-be-deleted)

Comment: Interesting observations. Have you ensured no other apps are running web views? It's a pain to force quit all the apps, so I typically power off the device and only open Safari to repeat the testing. You might be on to a bug or it could just be many processes accepting cookies in the background / foreground in addition to Mobile Safari.app

Comment: To be 100% sure I've tested it again: delete every entry one by one, then kick-out every process and then switching off. Starting the device again and going directly to configuration. The three entries are there.

Comment: At iPhone5 with 10.3.2 with more or less similar settings and on fact not very different surf history there is no entry reappearing. Strange.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have an iPhone 7 on 10.3.2 which is the latest update. Most cookies will delete but there's one still stuck that has 68k from a link that was accidentally clicked. I'm in the USA.

Answer (score 2):

Also encountered the same problem on my iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.2. There were some website data that could not be deleted and showed 0 bytes. It is definitely website specific as only a few domains keep popping up while others could be deleted. I tried rebooting my device, clearing safari history and manually deleting each cookie but nothing worked.

What fixed the problem was restoring my iPhone from a recent backup before I've visited the websites. I connected my iPhone to iTunes and clicked the 'Restore iPhone...' button on the device menu. After restoring, I set up my device from backup and all the unwanted website data were gone. Note that this may take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced similar problem on iPhone 6sPlus.   Appears to have been corrected in release 10.3.2 14F89.   Just downloaded this fixpack about 10pm last night (23 May) .   Immediately after install,  cookie deletion on my iPhone 6sPlus returned to normal ... they way it used to work before.   Problem has been resolved for me.  Your experience may be different.

Comment: I've already installed 10.3.2 on my iPad (Version 14F89), trying for new version getting the result "your system has the newest version". I'm not sure, the update was executet 22nd of may (local time), perhaps earlier (both devices - iPhone and iPad).